# Ember: Router pre and post hooks connectOutlets

Tags: ember.js, hook, ember-old-router

I want to call some function before and after every connectOutlets call in Ember Router. I am not able to find anything in the Ember documentation.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

From the "[Understanding the Ember.js Router: A Primer](http://emberjs.com/guides/router_primer/)" guide:

> Every Ember.Route fires an enter and exit callback. Here is a suitable
>   place to insert logging and debugging data as has already appeared in
>   this application.
>
> Setting the enableLogging property to true within the Router also
>   helpfully display's the Router's decision-making process. When the
>   browser's debug console is open, the router will print helpful error
>   messages beginning with STATEMANAGER.

You can use the `enter` and `exit` callbacks as follows:

```
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
    enableLogging: true,
    root: Ember.Route.extend({

        gotoHome: Em.Route.transitionTo('root.home'),
        gotoInfo: Em.Route.transitionTo('root.info'),

        index: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/',
            redirectsTo: 'home'
        }),
        home: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/home',
            connectOutlets: function(router) {
              router.get('applicationController')
                    .connectOutlet("home");
            },
            enter: function(router){
                console.log('The "enter" event of "home" route has been fired');
            },
            exit: function(router) {
                console.log('The "exit" event of "home" route has been fired');
            }
        }),
        info: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/info',
            connectOutlets: function(router) {
              router.get('applicationController')
                    .connectOutlet("info");
            },
            enter: function(router){
                console.log('The "enter" event of "info" route has been fired');
            },
            exit: function(router) {
                console.log('The "exit" event of "info" route has been fired');
            }

        })
    })
});
```

Check [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/qAPVP/) with the browser console open so you can see the logs when you enter/leave a route.

**Edit**: 
If you just want to update the current selected menu based on the route, you don't need to have events hooked up after or before you connect outlets, you actually need your "menu controller" to have a property that keeps track of the selected item and when you enter a given route you update that controller. Your "menu view" will have child menu items with a `classNameBindings` that is feed based on the selected in the controller (which you can bind to the parent view). [**This fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/hEx84/) already has it implemented so I'm not gonna write another, but check it out and look at the `NavigationController`, `NavigationView` (and `NavigationItemView`) & the routes. In each `connectOutlet` I am updating the selected menu item in the controller like this:

`router.set('navigationController.selected', 'MY ROUTE NAME GOES HERE');`

Hope this helps

Comment: I want a commom pre and post function to be called for each router. I dont want to keep adding the same function for every new route. A good usecase: Update the current Selected menu based on the route.

Comment: I am already aware of this method. Thats the most easy way to do that. But I dont want to add code to explicity set the latest Menu in every route. All I want to add a common function which will be called automatically by ember framework when route changes, So I can have common logic in there. Make sense ?

Comment: I was trying to create a custom route by extending `Em.Route` and use the context to provide the route name and path to it, then the actual route in the application router would use that custom route but I didn't have much success. I'm a little intrigued about this, so I might give it another shot at a later time, but right now I got nothing

Comment: I think extending the connectOutlets in Ember.Route can solve this usecase. What I have in mind is in connectOutlet call preHook, then some other function name say "connectionOutletAdvanced" and then call postHook only if they exists.

Comment: Ember.js Router Primer link is broken. ;(